Singular points in a parametrized surface
I am just starting with a differential geometry course, so please bear with my question.
Given a parametrized surface $X(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$, I am tasked to find all the singular points in the surface.
I know that a singular point is a point in the surface where the set of tangent vectors is not maximal (in this case, 2). However, I do not know how to solve for this points. Is it sufficient to solve for the differential given by the matrix
$$dX =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \ \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \ \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \ \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and then solve for $u$ and $v$ such that the resulting matrix is not a 2-dimensional subspace? If this is the case, would it just be direct substitution to solve for the point $(x,y,z)$?

I'm sure the intention of the exercise is to find the values of $(u,v)$ for which the derivative matrix has rank $<2$. The problem with this is that there might be a different parametrization which works just fine. Consider, for example, spherical coordinates parametrizing the standard unit sphere. The parametrization fails at the poles and along one semicircle joining them (of course, those values are not usually included in the domain of the parametrization).
